# how to add thousands of image into a pdf with reportlab

Tags: pdf, reportlab

I have one thousand PNG images,and use reportlab to add 
these images into a PDF,
the code is:

def pic_exits(pic_path):

```
if os.path.exists(pic_path):
    #print ('pic_exits')
    #print (pic_path)
    target = PIL.Image.open(pic_path)            
    #fp = open(pic_path,'rb')
    #target = PIL.Image.open(fp)
    #fp.close()        
    targetx,targety = target.size
    del target
    #print (targetx,targety)
    tx,ty = get_xy(targetx,targety)
    targetimg = Image(pic_path, tx, ty)
else:
    targetimg = Paragraph('<para align = center>not exist</para>',Bodystyle)      
return targetimg
```

def draw_sourcepic(self_dir,pic_list):

```
pic = [pic_list[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(pic_list),3)]
data = []
i = 0
for val in pic:
    eachline = []

    for pic_path in val:
        i+=1
        pic_image = pic_exits(pic_path)
        eachline.append(pic_image)
    while len(eachline) < 3:
        eachline.append(None)
    data.append(eachline)       
pic_table = drawTable(data,(150,150,150),None)
Story.append(pic_table)
```

but its has the below error:
    IOError: Cannot open resource "C:\workspace\decode\2012\result\pic\510.png
which maybe means that I hava opened too many images,

The offical documents said that:
    an image (digital picture). Formats supported by PIL/Java 1.4 (the Python/Java Imaging Library are supported. At the present time images as flowables are always centered horozontally
in the frame. We allow for two kinds of lazyness to allow for many images in a document
which could lead to file handle starvation.
lazy=1 don't open image until required.
lazy=2 open image when required then shut it.

But when I changed to this:
     targetimg = Image(pic_path, tx, ty, lazy = 2)
its has the following error:
     AttributeError: ._file

how can I add thousands of images into a PDF? The question is long,

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a year late, but I recently encountered a similar problem. I think this is a problem with reportlab--when lazy=2, the image is called upon again after its needed file attribute been destroyed. I've reported the issue and my workaround [here](https://bitbucket.org/rptlab/reportlab/issue/41/attributeerror-raised-when-displaying). Hope it helps.